# How to read data from a v-for (vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Given the next v-for:

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp" style="display:none;">
     <div class="row" >
       <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6" >
         <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light" >
         <div class="card-header text-center" > {{ result.title }} </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="/details" class="btn btn-info" @click="getData(result)" >Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

And the next Vue.js script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#networdapp',
    data: {
     results:[]
    },

    methods: {

    getData: function(result){
    window.alert($(this).parents("#networdapp").find(".card-header.text-center").outerHTML);
    window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName("card-header").outerHTML);
    window.alert(result.outerHTML);
     }

    },

     mounted() {
   axios.get('/getJson')
     .then(response => {
    this.results = response.data;
    })
      .catch( e => {
   console.log(e);
     });
     }
   });

     </script>
```

I want to get data from a specific iteration,let's say if I click the "Details" button of the 3rd div from the v-for I want to get the {{result.title }} data from the 3rd for.Is it possible?I've been reading the Vue.js documentation but I  didn't find anything about reading the data from DOM.If it is not possible,than how can I do that without Vue.js?Is there any other option?
The main goal is to get this data and to put it into a js object passing it to another webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from a FOR with DIVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234506/how-to-read-data-from-a-for-with-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass index key and use is to get from **results**'s position.

change the for loop div into

```
<div  v-for="(result,i) in results" :key="i" class="col-sm-6" >
```

also chnange the methods parameter

```
<a href="/details" class="btn btn-info" @click="getData(i)" >Details</a>
```

and the method will get the index key and here i have used console to see the result.title that you have wanted. you can use it any how you want.

```
getData: function(key){
console.log(this.results[key].title)
 }
```

so
Given the next v-for:

```
 <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp" style="display:none;">
     <div class="row" >
       <div  v-for="(result,i) in results" :key="i" class="col-sm-6" >
         <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light" >
         <div class="card-header text-center" > {{ result.title }} </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="/details" class="btn btn-info" @click="getData(i)" >Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

And the next Vue.js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#networdapp',
    data: {
     results:[]
    },

    methods: {

    getData: function(key){
    console.log(this.results[key].title)
     }

    },

     mounted() {
   axios.get('/getJson')
     .then(response => {
    this.results = response.data;
    })
      .catch( e => {
   console.log(e);
     });
     }
   });
```

Comment: You sir,are a life savior

Answer (score 0):

To get the data you want to access in the results array, you can use an index in your v-for loop

```
v-for="(result, index) in results"
```

you can check the docs here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

I also strongly recommend you to add a key attribute after the v-for to help vue.js
keep track of each result, see  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: Thank you for help!